# Map XML accordingly

Tags: php, xml, mapping

I am having trouble finding a solution to a problem I am facing, parsing XMLs.
Let me describe what I have now and what's the issue:

I have LINKs of XMLs files that have for example:

```
<prodcuts>
..
<product>
<id>1</id>
<name><![CDATA[ this is a test product name ]]></name>
<link><![CDATA[http://www.google.com]]></link>
<image><![CDATA[http://www.google.com/image.jpg]]></image>
<sku><![CDATA[ ]]></sku>
<category><![CDATA[ System > Technology ]]></category>
<price>20</price>
<description><![CDATA[ ]]></description>
<instock><![CDATA[ Y ]]></instock>
<availability>Y</availability>
</product>
..
</products>
```

Another XML has:

```
<prodcuts>
    ..
<product>
<productID>1</productID>
<title><![CDATA[  ]]></title>
<link><![CDATA[http://www.google.com]]></link>
<image><![CDATA[http://www.google.com/image.jpg]]></image>
<sku><![CDATA[ ]]></sku>
<categoryPath><![CDATA[ System > Technology ]]></categoryPath>
<price>20</price>
<description><![CDATA[ ]]></description>
<instock><![CDATA[ Y ]]></instock>
<availability>Y</availability>
<size>40</size>
</product>
..
</products>
```

Now, the difference between those are

1) the first one has a tag name "name", the other one has a tag name "title".
2) The second one has some tags that the first one does not.

Now the problem is, I am parsing the XML file via PHP like this:

```
$xml->products->product[$i]->id
$xml->products->product[$i]->name
```

and so on.. If I do this the code I have wrote, will work only for the first one. The tags that are missing is not a problem for now, cause I am inserting to Database NULL cause there are not required fields..

But, what about the second XML? Can I do something "automatically" in order to avoid asking to correct those tags? 
This could be done only manually, by grabbing the content of this LINK (via PHP) and rename those ones?

I do not have the file from my clients, just the LINK of XML.

thanks in advance!

Comment: `$name = $xml->product->title or $name = $xml->product->name ;`

Comment: thanks for your reply.. The above code was an example.. I do not know the tag names, until I get the URL link of XML. So, what you just wrote could not work.. I want for my clients to give me the link and do something "automatically" no matter what the tag names are... Could I map those tags somehow, without knowing the tag names?

Comment: you can parse all xml tags but I cant advice you what information is contained tag with unknown name. al least, you should make table of synonyms

Comment: I was thinking to grab all the ELEMENT of <product> tag, for example: <productID>,<title><link> or whatever my client send me inside of <product> INSERT those to my DB and then match those with my tags (through an Admin Dashboard or something)..

In this case, I will replace XML tags with mine while I am running the PHP and read the XML.

Is that a good plan, or not?

*thanks for taking time to answer my questions..

Comment: Plan, which requests manually parse xml, is very effective. if amount of files and item is not huge, you can. Moreover, instead replacing tags you can take marked tags value into result array/table...

Comment: What do you mean by saying take marked tags value into result array/table? These XMLs have from 200 to 3000 or more products.. It could  be hard to do it manually always and XMLs are many... Moreover, these XMLs will be updated probably more than once per day.. I am trying to find the best solution to INSERT those product informations to DB.. How can  I do this, when the element tags of XMLs are different to each other?

Comment: *How can I do this, when the element tags of XMLs are different to each other?* - i don't know :(

Comment: ok.. How could I read the **children element tags** of the first <product> ? I mean the <productID>, <title>, <link> e.t.c. and NOT the values of these? I would like to take the children of <product> tag..

Comment: `foreach($xml->products->product[$i]->children as $child)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok! I believe I have found some solutions to my problem.. I wrote them here in case someone has the same issues:

Solutions:

i) Read all the children of XML file, no matter how they are written (case-sensitive) and add them to Database. After that, there is a dashboard/PHP file with SQL queries that MATCH those children elements tags of XML with the one that you want.
        In this case, you may want to create a file called whatever you like, for example test.xml and CREATE the one that you want, with the correct XML tag elements. In this case, you could UPDATE this, every some hour (according to your needs) via a cronjob..

ii) Create manually the PHP file with the parsing inside, for every XML that you get. Just make sure to keep the XML link in your DB

iii) Ask the client to give you the correct XML. XML is case-sensitive for a reason.

In case you choose the first solution you need to make changes to php.ini file too, cause the XML files may be too large and the max_execution_time is probably too low to run all these PHP - MySQL scripts.

if someone need more explain or have any better advice, please share!